# Cypher query to verify all items in an ordered list are represented in order by a nodes in the graph with specified relationship

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am modeling a simple file system, with folders and files.

```
(:Folder)<-[:IS_IN *]-(:Folder)<-[:IS_IN]-(:File)
```

A user can give me an arbitrary path, `/foo/bar/baz.txt`. In this case the graph would look like:

```
(:Folder {Name: '/'})<-[:IS_IN]-(:Folder {Name: 'Foo'})<-[:IS_IN]-(:Folder {Name: 'bar'})<-[:IS_IN]-(:File {Name: 'baz.txt'})
```

Without knowing how long the path a user will supply, is there a good way to query whether a given path is represented in the graph? If I split path into an ordered list of folder names, can I write a query that returns the nodes if and only if they exist in the same order as the list?

Naively I can dynamically generate a query with each node, but I'd rather not generate dynamic queries.

Comment: Shouldn't `(:Folder {Name: '/'})` be `(:Folder {Name: '/'})<-[:IS_IN]-(:Folder {Name: 'foo'})`?

Comment: @cybersam yep, I missed “foo”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you pass this `$path` [parameter](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-node-id), and that the last element in the path is a file:

```
"/foo/bar/baz.txt"
```

And assuming that your data looks like this:

```
(:Folder {Name: '/'})<-[:IS_IN]-
  (:Folder {Name: 'foo'})<-[:IS_IN]-
    (:Folder {Name: 'bar'})<-[:IS_IN]-
      (:File {Name: 'baz.txt'})
```

This should work:

```
WITH SPLIT($path, '/') AS p
WITH REVERSE(CASE WHEN p[0] = '' THEN ['/']+p[1..] ELSE p END) AS names
OPTIONAL MATCH (file:File {Name: names[0]})
RETURN REDUCE(s=file, n IN names[1..] |
  CASE WHEN s IS NOT NULL THEN [(s)-[:IS_IN]->(f1 {Name: n})|f1][0] END
) IS NOT NULL AS found
```

The query will return whether the path in `$path` is found.

It breaks up the $path string into an array of folder and file names, reverses it, and then [optionally matches](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/optional-match/) the file node. We use an OPTIONAL MATCH so that the query always returns a value, even when the file is not found. Then we use the [REDUCE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/list/#functions-reduce) function to loop through the remaining folders in the path to verify that each needed relationship exists. We use a [pattern comprehension](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/lists/#cypher-pattern-comprehension) to perform matches within the loop.